# How to hide parent's parent element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code , I want when the button 'Accept' is clicked , the whole `<tr>` tag to be hidden by the style 'display:none;'. at the moment , the button hides the `<td>` and I don't want it to be like that. I want it to hide the whole table row.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Skype</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    <th>Accept?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>email@gmail.com</td>
    <td>skypename</td>
    <td>phone</td>
    <td>MESSAGE</td>
    <td><button onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Deny</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery tag if you obviously don't use it

Comment: `this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none'`?

Comment: So if `.parentElement` gets you from the button to the `td`, how do you suppose you'll get from the `td` to the `tr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<button onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned jQuery you can do it this way

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Skype</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>Accept?</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>email@gmail.com</td>
        <td>skypename</td>
        <td>phone</td>
        <td>MESSAGE</td>
        <td><button onclick="$(this).parents('tr').hide()" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Deny</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Won't it hide the `table` tag? OP wants to hide the `tr` tag.

Comment: Yes , It hides the table tag. I don't want that. I need to hide the current <tr>  tag that the element is in.